# What is the difference between Proxy constructor and Reflect?

Tags: javascript, reflection, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

Is there any significant difference between [Reflect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) and [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)?

From what is documented, it seems that they have pretty much the same capabilities, apart from:

- Reflect being capable of specifying only one trap at the time.
- Proxy being [revocable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/revocable).
- Proxy being a constructor.

If the list above sums up all the differences, then what is the rationale for having both?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Reflect and Proxy have completely different purposes and different capabilities.

[MDN describes Proxy in this way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

> The **`Proxy`** object is used to define custom behavior for fundamental operations (e.g. property lookup, assignment, enumeration, function invocation, etc).

[And Reflect in this way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect):

> **Reflect** is a built-in object that provides methods for interceptable JavaScript operations. The methods are the same as those of [proxy handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler).

I realize that you've probably already read that, so I'll use an example to explain it further.

Let's say you have an object:

```
const obj = {
  a: 'foo',
  b: 'bar',
};
```

You can access property `a` using a property accessor like this:

```
console.log(obj.a); // 'foo'
```

You can do the same using `Reflect.get()` method:

```
console.log(Reflect.get(obj, 'a')); // 'foo'
```

You can also create a proxy of that object using the Proxy constructor. We'll use the `get` handler for intercepting all property lookups.

```
const proxy = new Proxy(obj, {
  get(target, property) {
    return property in target ? target[property] : 'default';
  },
});
```

Now using either property accessor or `Reflect.get()` to get an undefined property results in string `'default'`:

```
console.log(proxy.c); // 'default'
console.log(Reflect.get(proxy, 'c')); // 'default'
```

---

Proxy and Reflect can work great together. You can for example create a Proxy with a no-op `get` handler using Reflect:

```
new Proxy(obj, {
  get: Reflect.get,
});
```

Answer (score 9):

`Proxy` is a wrapper around an object, that forwards operations on it to the object, optionally trapping some of them. The Proxy object allows you to create an object that can be used in place of the original object, but which may redefine fundamental Object operations like getting, setting, and defining properties.

[image: Proxy]

`Reflect` API is designed to complement Proxy. Internal methods such as `[[Get]]`, `[[Set]]` and others are specification-only, can’t be called directly. The `Reflect` object makes that somewhat possible.

So `Proxy` is a wrapper which can be used to intercept fundamental operations like `[[Get]]` and `[[Set]]` on an object whereas `Reflect` provides us minimal wrappers around these fundamental operations like `[[Get]]` and `[[Set]]` so that we can call them directly (Usually from inside the trap).

**------------ How Reflect complements Proxy ------------**

For every internal method, trappable by `Proxy`, there’s a corresponding method in `Reflect`, with the same name and arguments as the Proxy trap. **(!Important)**

Let's see this example to demonstrate how it is useful.

```
let user = {
  _name: "Guest",
  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
};

let userProxy = new Proxy(user, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
    // return target[prop];
  }
});

alert(userProxy.name); // Guest
```

In the above example, inside the `get` trap, both `return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);` and `return target[prop];` will print the same output (`Guest`).

Lets take an example that is little bit more complex to demonstrate why `Reflect.get` is better and why `get/set` have the third argument `receiver`.

Lets create an object `admin` which inherits from `user`:

```
let user = {
  _name: "Guest",
  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
};

let userProxy = new Proxy(user, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    return target[prop]; // (*) target = user
  }
});

let admin = {
  __proto__: userProxy,
  _name: "Admin"
};

// Expected: Admin
alert(admin.name); // outputs: Guest (?!?)
```

Reading `admin.name` should return `"Admin"`, not `"Guest"`!

The problem is actually in the proxy, in the line `(*)`.

1. When we read `admin.name`, as `admin` object doesn’t have such own property, the search goes to its prototype.
2. The prototype is `userProxy`.
3. When reading `name` property from the proxy, its `get` trap triggers and returns it from the original object as `target[prop]` in the line `(*)`. A call to `target[prop]`, when `prop` is a getter, runs its code in the context `this=target`. So the result is `this._name` from the original object `target`, that is: from `user`.

To fix this we need to pass correct `this` to the getter. `receiver`, the third argument of get trap keeps the correct `this` to be passed to a getter (in our case that’s admin). For a regular function we can use `call/apply` to bind `this` value, but we cannot do the same for `getter` as it is not `called`, just accessed.

This is where `Reflect` is usefull. Remember, for every internal method, trappable by `Proxy`, there’s a corresponding method in `Reflect`, with the same name and arguments as the Proxy trap.

```
let user = {
  _name: "Guest",
  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
};

let userProxy = new Proxy(user, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) { // receiver = admin
    return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver); // (*)
  }
});


let admin = {
  __proto__: userProxy,
  _name: "Admin"
};

alert(admin.name); // Admin
```

For detailed explanation please refer to this wonderful article by Ilya Kantor : [Proxy and Reflect](https://javascript.info/proxy#proxy)

Comment: Nicely explained.